# Use of undeclared identifier in ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, undeclared-identifier

I know that its the kind that can be asked everyday, but the fact is that the answer can be  different for every questions, and I didn't find any yet.

I am currently a real beginner in Objective C, and I am developing an app using the framework `OpenCV`.

I have been following this [website](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/ios/image_manipulation/image_manipulation.html) for learning
and then I got my problem.

I copied/pasted the 3 methods that are given in the website to convert cv::Mat to UIImage and UIImage to cv::Mat, but I can't use them :

My *.pch file :

```
#import <Availability.h>

#ifndef __IPHONE_5_0
#warning "This project uses features only available in iOS SDK 5.0 and later."
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#endif

#ifdef __OBJC__
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#endif
```

My ViewController.hh file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

- (cv::Mat)cvMatFromUIImage:(UIImage *)image;
- (cv::Mat)cvMatGrayFromUIImage:(UIImage *)image;
- (UIImage *)UIImageFromCVMat:(cv::Mat)cvMat;
@end
```

and my ViewController.mm file

```
#import "ViewController.hh"

@interface ViewController ()

@end


@implementation ViewController

- (cv::Mat)cvMatFromUIImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    @@@//what is given in the linked website
    return cvMat;
}

- (cv::Mat)cvMatGrayFromUIImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    @@@//what is given in the linked website
    return cvMat;
}

-(UIImage *)UIImageFromCVMat:(cv::Mat)cvMat
{
    @@@//what is given in the linked website    
    return finalImage;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSString* filename = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"openCV" ofType:@"jpg"];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filename];

    cv::Mat inputMat = cvMatFromUIImage(image);
    UIImage *newImage = UIImageFromCVMat(inputMat);

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:newImage];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"HelloWorld !" message:@"Welcome to OpenCV !" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Continue" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

@end
```

The 2 errors are on the lines that are alone in `(void) viewDidLoad` in the `.mm` file, it says that both `cvMatFromUIImage` and `UIImageFromCVMat` aren't declared.

It might be a stupid question, I guess that I missed something, but don't know what.

Please help me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've defined your functions in Objective-C but are using the C standard for calling them... Change these:

```
cvMatFromUIImage(image)
UIImageFromCVMat(inputMat)
```

to

```
[self cvMatFromUIImage:image];
[self UIImageFromCVMat:inputMat];
```

Comment: Ok thank you very much, got an otehr issu now, but step by step, it's going to be ok ^^